# Reverse Integer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/)

> Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: 123
>
> Output: 321
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: -123
>
> Output: -321
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: 120
>
> Output: 21
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store
>   integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2^31,  2^31 − 1]. For
>   the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when
>   the reversed integer overflows.

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {number}
 */
const reverse = x => {
  if (x === undefined || x === null) { return; }
  if (x < 10 && x >= 0) { return x; }

  const num = [];
  const dissectNum = n => {
    if (n <= 0) { return; }
    const y = n % 10;
    num.push(y);
    return dissectNum(Math.floor(n / 10));
  };
  dissectNum(Math.abs(x));
  let tmp = 0;
  const maxPow = num.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    tmp += num[i] * Math.pow(10, maxPow - i);
  }
  const result = (x < 0 ? -1 : 1 ) * tmp;
  return result > Math.pow(-2, 31) && result < (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)
    ? result
    : 0;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The question states that the input is a number 32 signed int so checking for `undefined` or `null` is a waste of time.

The solution is a little long. Some of it due to not being familiar with some old school short cuts.

- To  get the sign of a number use [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)

-JavaScript numbers are doubles but when you use bitwise operations on them they are converted to 32 bit signed integers. This gives you a very easy way to check if the result has overflowed.

```
const signedInt = value => (value | 0)  === value; // returns true if int32
```

- A 32 bit int can store 9 full decimal digits, with an extra digit `1` or `2`, and a sign. you dont need to use an array to hold the reversed digits you can store them in the reversed number as you go.
- JavaScript can handle hex `0x10 === 16`, decimal `10 === 10`, octal `010 === 8` and binary `0b10 === 2` (oh and BIG ints `10n === 10`) Hex makes realy easy to remember the lowest and highest int for a given size.

  Not that you need them to solve the problem, just some handy info.

Some common ways of writing min max 32Ints

```
 const MIN = Math.pow(-2, 31), MAX = Math.pow(2, 31) - 1;


// negative
-0x80000000 === MIN;      // true
(0x80000000 | 0) === MIN; // true. Coerce from double to int32 
1 << 31 === MIN;          // true. Shift 1 to the highest (MSB) bit for negative

//positive
0x7FFFFFFF === MAX; // true
~(1 << 31) === MAX; // true  Flips bits of min int32
```

### Rewrite

With that info you can rewrite the solution as

```
function reverseDigits(int) {
    var res = 0, val = Math.abs(int);
    while (val > 0) {
        res = res * 10 + (val % 10);
        val = val / 10 | 0;
    }
    res *= Math.sign(int);
    return (res | 0) === res ? res : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd just use string manipulation on this, with a simple conditional for the edge cases.

```
var reverse = n => {
  const s = parseInt([..."" + n].reverse().join(""));
  return s >= 2 ** 31 ? 0 : Math.sign(n) * s;
};
```

The approach is to stringify the number, arrayify the string, reverse it, re-join the array into a string and finally parse the reversed string to an integer. `parseInt` called on a string such as `"546-"` will strip the trailing `-`. Then, handle overflow and positive/negative conditions and return the result.

In short, avoid overcomplication and take advantage of high-level language features when possible.

Answer (score 2):

Both answers require you to use `Math.sign`. To avoid compatibility issues with some browsers, you could add the following script in your solution.

```
if (Math.sign === undefined) {
    Math.sign = function ( x ) {
        return ( x < 0 ) ? - 1 : ( x > 0 ) ? 1 : +x;
    };
}
```

Comment: "some browsers" in this case means [only the Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign).