# Reverse Integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Problem Description:**

> Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer in
>   JavaScript.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> - Input: 123
> - Output: 321
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> - Input: -123
> - Output: -321
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> - Input: 120
> - Output: 21
>
> **Note:** It should return zero when it reaches out of limit [−2 ^31,  2 ^31 − 1]

**My implementation**

```
var reverse = function (x) {
  var minRange = Math.pow(-2, 31)
  var maxRange = Math.pow(2, 31) - 1

  var isNegative = false;
  if (x < 0) {
    isNegative = true;
    x = (x - x - x);
  }
  var result = Number(x.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
  (isNegative) ? result = (result - result - result) : result;
  if (result < minRange || result > maxRange) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return result;
  }

};
```

Please help to improve.

Comment: Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220274

Comment: Check this out - https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/solution/, it might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- adding this as an answer because I can't comment.

The answer referenced in ggorlen's comment, can be improved by remarking that a (negative number % 10) is a negative number, so there is no need for sign checking.

```
const reverse = val => {
    let res = 0;
    const Base = 10;
    while (val) {
        res = res * Base + (val % Base);
        val = (val / Base) | 0;
    }
    return (res | 0) == res ? res : 0;
}
```

Tests:

```
reverse(1) === 1; 
reverse(-1) === -1 
reverse(0) === 0 
reverse(Math.pow(2,31) - 1) === 0 
reverse(Math.pow(-2,31)) === 0 
reverse(1463847412) === 2147483641
reverse(1463847413) === 0
```

By the way, what's the reasoning behind "x = (x - x - x)"? x-x evaluates to zero. so that's just x = - x.

Comment: +1 Welcome to CR. You can skip the sign but I will point out that numbers are converted to int in a standard way, ignoring the sign will only work for integers in range. Outside the range and you return the wrong value because to do not account for the correct conversion. Eg  `(new Int32Array([21474836481]))[0] === 1` yet you reverse it to `reverse(21474836481)  === 1536152588`

Comment: I don't understand, the question said we are guaranteed to receive a signed 32 bit integer.